# hide select options using only css

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a select and I need to hide some options using `css`, so I did :

```
<select name="time-2-hours" id="forminator-field-time-2-hours" class="forminator-select2 select2-hidden-accessible" data-field="hours" data-default-value="" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
<option value="0" selected="selected">00</option>
<option value="1">01</option>
<option value="2">02</option>
<option value="3">03</option>
<option value="4">04</option>
<option value="5">05</option>
<option value="6">06</option>
<option value="7">07</option>
<option value="8">08</option>
<option value="9">09</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
</select>
```

css:

```
 option[value="2"] {
    display: none;
}
```

but its not working is there some thing wrong in my code ? I also try :

```
select#forminator-field-time-2-hours option[value="2"] {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: The rendering of `<select>` and `<option>` are pretty much controlled by the OS/vendor. You should probably use JS to either remove the option or make the option unselectable using the `disabled` attribute

Comment: You can't hide `option`s this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do this by adding `style="display:none"` to the option you want to hide using `nth-child`, for example i did it to option 05 from your code by adding `select option:nth-child(6){ display:none; }` :

```css
select option:nth-child(6){ 
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<select name="time-2-hours" id="forminator-field-time-2-hours" class="forminator-select2 select2-hidden-accessible" data-field="hours" data-default-value="" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true">
<option value="0" selected="selected">00</option>
<option value="1">01</option>
<option value="2">02</option>
<option value="3">03</option>
<option value="4">04</option>
<option value="5">05</option>
<option value="6">06</option>
<option value="7">07</option>
<option value="8">08</option>
<option value="9">09</option>
<option value="10">10</option>
<option value="11">11</option>
<option value="12">12</option>
<option value="13">13</option>
<option value="14">14</option>
<option value="15">15</option>
<option value="16">16</option>
<option value="17">17</option>
<option value="18">18</option>
<option value="19">19</option>
<option value="20">20</option>
<option value="21">21</option>
<option value="22">22</option>
<option value="23">23</option>
</select>
```

Comment: i can't edit the html select i should add a style in css file that's the problem

Comment: @omayma i have changed my answer, please check and let me know if that solution works for you